# how can i change date languages in my Codeigniter projetc

Tags: codeigniter

I have a drop-down list for months it is fetched in English. What I want is to change it from English to Arabic.  I tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_EG');
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix English issues.  I also removed the markdown on the whole post, that's not necessary.  I think you need to provide a chunk of code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php ?

Comment: try this https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/i18n-Multi-language-Library-Helper